# Multistream Project v/s Single Stream project

Tags: code-reviews, clearcase

If we want to have code reviews before a developer delivers his work, then can you suggest whether multi stream project { i.e., each developer create his own stream and view and later deliver to single stream.} or single stream { i.e., all developers work on same stream } which is advisable.

Answer (score 2):

Multi-stream project is fine, and provide natural isolation through branching.

However, it doesn't scale well and force developer to multiple merges if they need to get the work of their colleagues.
So if they can develop in isolation and don't depend heavily and regularly on the work of their peers, multi-stream is fine.

That being said, I prefer this model when each stream represents a development effort, and not a developer (even though you still can match one developer to said development effort): see this [answer for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567135/clearcase-issue/1567308#1567308).